# Subquery returned more than 1 value This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I run the following query:

```
SELECT Date,
       Branch,
       Total,
       (SELECT CAST(AVG(Total) AS INT) 
          FROM MaySales 
         GROUP BY Branch) AS AvgSales
  FROM MaySales
```

The result I'm looking for is to display the monthly avg beside daily sales so I can do case statement .

| date | branch | day total | monthly avg | case statement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 05\05 | a | 4500 | 5000 | below avg |
| 05\06 | a | 5000 | 5000 | avg |
| 05\05 | b | 6000 | 4500 | above avg |

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results and formatted text (not images). The error is very clear, your sub-query is returning more than one result.

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.

Comment: In that case you need to correlate your sub-query to your main query. And you shouldn't need to cast anything.

Comment: Using a `group by` automatically assumes multiple rows. This shouldn't be a shock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current query tries to return multiple rows for an individual column, while the other columns return once per each row naturally. So it fails to execute. Perhaps using a correlated subquery would be a solution, but would not be an ideal one. Rather prefer using a window function such as:

```
SELECT Date, Branch, Total,
    AVG(Total) OVER (PARTITION BY Branch) AS AvgSales
FROM MaySales
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment within original question but it looks like your selecting all the rows from your MaySales table, which I'm assuming is for the month of May. In your subquery, and given your intention is to group by month, you have no month operator.

```
   SELECT year(date) as BranchYear, month(date) as BranchMonth, branch, CAST(avg(TOTAL) AS int)
     FROM MaySales
     GROUP BY year(date), month(date), Branch
```

Try something like the above to get your data down to a monthly granularity. Once you understand this, you'll be in a much better position to format your data on the assumption that you want to display your normal daily totals with your monthly total included.

Further to the above, I would move away from just having a 'MaySales' table as this would imply that you would have a table for every month of the year. What would happen then if data would extend for years? Have a 'BranchSales' table with DATE, branch, TOTAL columns which I'd assume are for daily totals and then you are in a position to calculate average totals for any time period you wish greater than a day including weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly totals

Comment: Syntax error, you might want to remove `) AS avgsales`

Comment: And in fact it appears OP wants to keep day totals, not just give a monthly summary.

Comment: Further to the above, I would move away from just having a 'MaySales' table as this would imply that you would have a table for every month of the year. What would happen then if data would extend for years? Have a 'BranchSales' table with DATE, branch, TOTAL columns which I'd assume are for daily totals and then you are in a position to calculate average totals for any time period you wish greater than a day including weekly, monthly, quarterly and yearly totals.

Comment: Indeed, you should add that to your answer.